# Adding editors in Visual Studio "Open With..." dialog box

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file

I added a batch (.bat) file to my project. I want to add a new *editor* for batch files that would actually execute this batch file in command prompt window.

What I did, but didn't remember my *editor*:

1. Right clicked on my .bat file
2. Selected **Open with...**
3. Clicked **Add**
4. Set program as "cmd /c" and some Friendly name
5. Accepted this dialog.
6. A new window appears that tells me it can't validate editor path (because of the additinoal parameter, because if I remove it, it works)
7. My new *editor* is in the window.

When I open the same **Open with...** dialog again, my *editor* isn't present.

How should I tackle this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok. I managed to solve this myself.
As I [found on the internet](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=114952) this is a Visual Studio bug, so it doesn't remember these kind of editors (parametrised executable file names). But nonetheless. The solution goes like this:

1. Create a separate batch file i.e. **ExecuteBatch.cmd**
2. Put this code in it:

   `@cmd /c %1`
3. Then add the new editor in Visual Studio by pointing to this **ExecuteBatch.cmd** file.

Voila. **Problem solved.** Detailed instructions can be found [in this blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/11/running-batch-files-bat-from-within.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot; that seems to do it. (With the annoying proviso that it has to be re-added for each file type you want to edit.) For the latest version of Emacs, my .cmd file contains: `@"C:\Program Files\emacs-24.2\bin\emacsclientw.exe" -na "C:\Program Files\emacs-24.2\bin\runemacs.exe" %1`

Comment: Oh. I can also verify that VS2012 (or at least the RC I've seen) has fixed this bug.

Answer (score 4):

According to the advice [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/SoftwareDoneRight/archive/2010/01/28/running-batch-files-from-the-solution-explorer-in-visual-studio.aspx) you can also use "Open With" PowerShell, and you don't have to worry about any parameters.

The instructions from that link are:

> You can run .bat files from the
> solution explorer directly by
> associating the default behavior of
> “.BAT” extensions to Powershell.
>
> 1. Right click the batch file in the Solution Explorer
> 2. Select “Open With…”  from the context menu
> 3. Click “Add…”
> 4. In the “Program name” textbox , specify the full path of PowerShell
>    (“\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe”)
> 5. In the “Friendly name” textbox enter “PowerShell”
> 6. Select “Set As Default”
> 7. Click OK
>
> Now when you double click your batch
> file in the solution explorer, it will
> shell out to powershell and execute.

Works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding upon the answers by Robert and Rustam, here is the RunBatch.bat script that I use as the "Open With" program for running batch files from Visual Studio:

```
@cd %~dp1
@call "%~n1%~x1"
```

The first line navigates to the file's folder and the second line runs the file.

This preserves the working directory in Visual Studio 2012 and later, and also supports batch files that have spaces in the file name.

Answer (score 2):

I just told visual studio to open the .bat file with windows explorer ;)

[image: Add Program dialog - explorer.exe]

Answer (score 1):

Additional suggestion: in VS2012 you can just use cmd.exe.

But! The drawback is that your bat file will start in VS home folder, not in your soultion's folder. That's why I used [this recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100227/adding-editors-in-visual-studio-open-with-dialog-box/1100428#1100428), but extended it a little. My .bat file is:

```
:: Navigate to file's folder
@cd %~dp1

:: Run file in its folder
@cmd /c %~n1%~x1
```

Syntax is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797983/can-a-dos-batch-file-determine-its-own-file-name)