# Can a Windows batch file determine its "invoked" filename when invoked with shortcut?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Can a Windows batch file determine its invoked filename when invoked through a shortcut?

For example, I create `real.bat`, and create its shortcut named `phony.bat` (`.lnk`?)

And invoke `phony` by double-click on it.

Can this batch file detect the name `phony.bat` instead of `real.bat`?

Of course I can just copy it to another name, but when I edit one of them, I have to manually sync the content to all files.

The question is related to [Can a Windows batch file determine its own file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797983/can-a-windows-batch-file-determine-its-own-file-name), but different.

Comment: I don't think so, because `phony.lnk` is never executed, only `real.bat`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oh... I want to do something like busybox, detects the invoked name and do different things.

Comment: are you able to edit the `.lnk` file properties?

Comment: @npocmaka: I don't know how to do it with batch command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh yeah, I found hardlink useful in this case:

```
mklink /h <link-name> <source-file>
```

I can create many hardlinks with different name, and they all points to the same file, so I can freely edit any one of them without manually sync their content.

Answer (score 1):

As in your you mentioned that you've created the shortcut I assume you can create the with any properties you want.

So right click on your `lnk` file and change the the target line to:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "set "lnk_call=1"&"C:\PATH\TO\your.bat" "
```

This will change the icon of the link so to set back to batch file cog click on change icon and find the bat file icon in :

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\SHELL32.dll
```

Finally in your bat put this line:

```
if defined lnk_call echo triggered from lnk file
```

the `lnk_call` now can be used to determine if your file is called from double clicking on a .lnk file. I don't think it is possible to detect this from a shortcut that anyone else created.

Comment: Wow it's brilliant, save the original filename in property. Just a little bit troublesome that I have to edit every `lnk` files

Comment: @Cychih To do this automatically(through command line) you can check this: https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/shortcutJS.bat